# how to query for distinct year in django

Tags: django

my model has creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

I have no idea how would i query for a distinct years on the database on this column.

Any idea would be  much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the model stores the `models.DateTimeField` it's normally in this format "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS" and you can use the filter method to query all the the specific records with that year.

Here's an example:

models.py

```
    from django.db import models

    class Items(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
    from Items.model import Items

        def items_by_creationdate_view(request):
            items = Items.objects.filter(creation_date__year=2013)
            return render("template.html", {"items": items })
```

template.html

```
{% for x in items %}
    {{x.name}}<br/>
    {{x.creation_date }}<br/><br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks you answering, What I wan to have is to get all distinct year for example the database has 50 rows, 10 are created on 2010, 30 are 2011, and 10 are 2013.

Comment: the result shoud be [2010, 2011, 2013]

Comment: Use the `.all()` and order by creation_date
`items = Items.objects.all().order_by(creation_date)`

Comment: Sorry missed the quotes
`items = Items.objects.all().order_by('creation_date')`

Comment: `items = Items.objects.extras(select={'creation_date_year': 'YEAR(creation_date)'}, order_by=['creation_date_year'])` and `items = Items.objects.all().order_by('creation_date')` should return the same results if I'm not mistaken. Actually `.all()` might work better because it'll sort down to the second because it's comparing the whole field.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it but you could try:

`set([instance.creation_date.year for instance in Model.objects.all()])`